# Python: Gaussian filtering an N-channel image along only spatial dimensions?

Tags: python

I have an `HxWxN` image `arr` that I want to Gaussian blur.

`scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter` seems to treat the image as a generic array and also blur along the final channel dimension. The desired behavior is Gaussian blurring `arr[:, :, i]` independently for all `i`s and then concatenating the resultant slices back into an `HxWxN` result array.

Is there a better library or function that I can use to directly achieve that, or do I really need to just put `scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter` in a for-loop over `i`?

A bonus question is what if I have M images organized as an `MxHxWxN` array? How do I blur over just the H and W dimensions?

Answer (score 2):

## Using `scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter`

### Solution

To Gaussian blur only the spatial dimensions `H` and `W` of an `H`x`W`x`N` image `arr` with a standard deviation of 1.6, use:

```py
std=1.6
gaussian_filter(arr, sigma=(std, std, 0))
```

### Explanation

According to the [SciPy Docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter.html) `scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter` allows to specify the standard derivation for each axis individually by passing a sequence of scalars to the parameter ***sigma***:

> **sigma: *scalar or sequence of scalars***
>
> Standard deviation for Gaussian kernel. The standard deviations of the Gaussian filter are given for each axis as a sequence, or as a single number, in which case it is equal for all axes.

Setting ***sigma*** to `0` for an axis means no filtering in this direction.

If only one scalar is given for ***sigma***, not only the spatial dimensions but also the RGB channels of an image would be blurred together leading to a desaturated image.

### Bonus Answer

For an array of `M` images with the shape `MxHxWxN` you would set `sigma=(0,std, std, 0)`

### Performance

After a quick look into the [source code of `scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.9.3/scipy/ndimage/_filters.py#L264-L347) it seems that the method `gaussian_filter1d` is applied [only to those dimensions that have a `sigma > 1e-15`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.9.3/scipy/ndimage/_filters.py#L339). With `sigma=0` not being `> 1e-15` the filtering is skipped for this dimension. So this solution should not cause any unnecessary calculations.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

`cv2.GaussianBlur()` does exactly that: it blurs each channel independently, and the image can have an arbitrary number of channels.